# Converting Pandas to Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to implement the following code, which was written with pandas, into a more generic version using only Numpy. The code is also [found here](https://medium.com/@rakendd/decision-tree-from-scratch-9e23bcfb4928):

```
attribute = 'Taste'
target_variables = df.Eat.unique()  #This gives all 'Yes' and 'No'
variables = df[attribute].unique()    #This gives different features in that attribute (like 'Sweet')
entropy_attribute = 0
for variable in variables:
    entropy_each_feature = 0
    for target_variable in target_variables:
        num = len(df[attribute][df[attribute]==variable][df.Eat ==target_variable]) #numerator
        den = len(df[attribute][df[attribute]==variable])  #denominator
        fraction = num/(den+eps)  #pi
        entropy_each_feature += -fraction*log(fraction+eps) #This calculates entropy for one feature like 'Sweet'
    fraction2 = den/len(df)
    entropy_attribute += -fraction2*entropy_each_feature   #Sums up all the entropy ETaste
```

Here is my attempt so far:

```
def entropy_by_attribute(dataset, feature):
    attribute = dataset[,:feature]
    target_variables = numpy.unique(dataset[:,-1])

    variables = numpy.unique(attribute)

    entropy_attribute = 0

    for variable in variables:
        entropy_each_feature = 0
        for target_variable in target_variables:
            num =
            den =
            fraction = num / (den + eps)
            entropy_each_feature = entropy_each_feature + (-fraction*log(fraction+eps))

        fraction2 = den/len(dataset)

        entropy_attribute  = entropy_attribute + (-fraction2*entropy_each_feature)

    return abs(entropy_attribute)
```

**What I am confused about is how to convert the numerator and denominator lines. I don't understand what `len(df[attribute][df[attribute]==variable][df.Eat ==target_variable])` is doing.**

For reference, here is the dataset the pandas example is using:

```
dataset = {'Taste':['Salty','Spicy','Spicy','Spicy','Spicy','Sweet','Salty','Sweet','Spicy','Salty'],
       'Temperature':['Hot','Hot','Hot','Cold','Hot','Cold','Cold','Hot','Cold','Hot'],
       'Texture':['Soft','Soft','Hard','Hard','Hard','Soft','Soft','Soft','Soft','Hard'],
       'Eat':['No','No','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','Yes']}
```

Can someone help me understand the `num` and `den` declarations so I can continue this conversion? I do not understand what they represent in this instance, or what `eps` is.

Thank you

Comment: I think I figured it out. is num the # of times that value appears per class (label), and the denominator is the total # of appearances of that value? If you have code that is better than my understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num` calculates the amount of times there is a row that both contains the target variable of Eat ('Yes' or 'No') and the variable attribute .

`den` calculates the amount of times the variable attribute is present.

Let's take 'Salty' as Taste attribute and 'No' as target variable of Eat. Now the numerator will be 2 since we have two ('No', 'Salty') pairs and the denominator will be three since there are three appearances of 'Salty'.

If you look at the link you provided, you'll find the meaning of eps.
    `eps = np.finfo(float).eps`

I quote:

> ‘eps’ here is the smallest representable number. At times we get log(0) or 0 in the denominator, to avoid that we are going to use this.

Eps is used to avoid dividing by zero by using the smallest possible number in that case.

Calculating `num` and `den` without using pandas can be done like this:

```
attribute = 'Taste'
variables = numpy.unique(dataset[attribute])
target_variables = numpy.unique(dataset["Eat"])
entropy_attribute = 0
for variable in variables:
entropy_each_feature = 0
for target_variable in target_variables:
    num = 0
    den = 0
    for index in range(0,len(dataset[attribute])):
        if dataset[attribute][index] == variable and dataset["Eat"][index] == target_variable:
            num += 1
        if dataset[attribute][index] == variable:
            den += 1
```

There might be a faster/cleaner way using numpy operations instead of index based comparisons but I'm not very familiar with it.